# How to open files out of long directory trees using helm-find-files?

Tags: buffers, helm, navigation

Helm features buffer navigation that is more powerful than ido but apparently has a bit of a learning curve. Say I want to open a file in

```
java/com/example/apple/banana/cat/dog/elephant/fig/grape/Hello.java
```

And my mini buffer currently reads

```
Find files or Url: ~/java/com
```

The helm buffer list will not let me <TAB> for completion like in ido. <RETURN> will open the buffer list, which is also not what I want. However to select the directory I must hit the right arrow key which requires leaving the home keys on my keyboard and is therefore very slow.

Per answer below `C-j` or `C-z` is the answer I'm looking for. However at that point it's still very hard to navigate, as Helm will default to `./` as the directory listed, i.e.:

1. Go to `helm-find-files`
2. Pick any directory
3. After you are taken to the next file list, the entry highlighted in "green" will be `the_directory/.`

This means if you type `C-j` again it will "take" you to exactly where you are. This contrasts with ido, where hitting <RETURN> a few times will auto-complete out using logic (I think just "last picked directory") to determine which directory should be default.

Therefore I must always type `C-n` twice or type the first letter of the directory. It certainly doesn't "fly" like ido-mode does, so this is still too unusable for me. Is there a hack for this as well?

Comment: You should be able to hit `C-z` (`helm-execute-persistent-action`) for completion in the same manner that you want to hit `TAB`. I swapped these two keys as @tuhdo recommends in his popular helm guide.

Comment: @nanny I saw that in the guide but didn't really understand what a "persistent action" is. I guess it does this, for one.

Comment: Others answered your question but [my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) could make Helm more enjoyable for you. Use my sample config in the guide for `TAB` to go in directory.

Comment: @TuDo ah, that's yours, great job. I followed the below answer but it still didn't completely solve my problem, see edit.

Comment: @TuDo: That guide is sweet, it's what got me to start using helm in the first place.

Comment: I found helm vastly superior to ido out of the box. Could be since I'm using helm-mini a lot more than helm-find-file. Then you have access to the recent files you've visited at very few keypresses. There might still be a way to achieve what you want, but now I see which use case you're after, and that I'm not working in that way. helm-projectile is also a great booster of efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solutions to this problem:

- Use `helm-find` instead, which, as in unix find, will search recursively.
- Use `helm-projectile` with projectile instead.

Comment: Using `helm-find` with a prefix argument (`C-u C-x c /` on my system) is exactly what I was looking for. The prefix argument makes `helm-find` prompt for where to start the search from. Note that the pattern you type using `find -name` pattern syntax. I'm already using projectile, but I want something that supports quick finding when I'm not inside a projectile project.

Answer (score 2):

`C-c ?` is your friend when it comes to Helm for context dependent help. So hit that when you're in helm-find-files, and it will tell you that `C-j` will expand to a file (or directory) name. When the candidate directory you want is highlighted, hit `C-j` and continue your travels from that directory, like you woud with `return` in ido.

Further, `C-l` will remove the current directory/file name, allowing for new input.

Comment: Thanks! This is good but didn't fully solve my problem, see edit.

Comment: @djechlin: Not sure I understand what you mean, maybe C-l is what you're looking for?

Comment: Not that; see edit again.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the "Helm" way, but I will argue that executing the first action with TAB instead of C-z is easier for my brain and hands. This is more evident when I want to traverse long directory structures.

As such, I recommend rebinding C-z to Tab and viceversa. I have this in my config:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; rebind tab to do persistent action
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; make TAB works in terminal
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z")  'helm-select-action) ; list actions using C-z
```